# Why does C++ allow nested namespace with same name?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Codes bellowing compiles:

```
namespace x
{
namespace y
{
    namespace x
    {
    struct C
    {
    C ()
    {
    std::cout << "x::y::z::C" << std::endl;
    }
    };
    }
}
struct C
{
    C ()
    {
    std::cout << "x::C" << std::endl;
    }
};
}
```

`x::C` and `x::y::x::C` are not same, but it's sometimes confusing.

Why is `x::y::x` allowed in C++? Isn't it more clear to forbid this?

Comment: "*Isn't it more clear to forbid this?*" - why?

Comment: It's not C++'s fault for you using bad naming conventions.  You're in a new scope so you can reuse an unreserved name you want, that's part of the power of scopes.

Comment: @Fureeish I suppose some newbie might mistake these two `C`.

Comment: That's why experienced C++ developers don't do this, to avoid confusing the newbies.

Comment: If "is sometimes confusing" was the only criteria, you'd need to throw the vast majority of C++ out of the window.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based based on this: *"Why is `x::y::x` allowed in C++? Isn't it more clear to forbid this?"*

Comment: I'd say that C++ in general has very poor rules regarding naming constraints. For example the same name can be reused for unrelated purposes: `namespace fff{ struct fff { } fff; }`. C++ would definitely have a better reputation if naming wasn't messed up that badly.

Comment: it is not c++ spirit to forbid things that are confusing or that enable you to write confusing or wrong code. C++ is not ... well, there are other languages that follow that spirit, but not C++

Comment: Allowing the unambiguous reuse of names is the whole point of namespaces.

Comment: There are very many ways to shoot your own leg in C++. If you remove most of them you will get java. Unfortunately loosing ability of shooting your leg you also loosing ability to write very efficient code. You are free to restrict yourself and your team though.

Comment: @Slava maybe jumping through a burning hoop while juggling with chainsaws is a better picture. Compared to shooting your leg it puts a bit more emphasize on how nice it can be if you get it right ;)

Answer (score 4):

> Why is x::y::x allowed in C++? Isn't it more clear to forbid this?

No offense, but I think your premise is seriously flawed.

Maybe you didn't notice but having names being the same on different levels of nesting is something very natural. Consider constructors. The fully qualified name of a constructor of class `foo` is `foo::foo()`. Nothing unusual is it?

Now what if I want to put my class inside a namespace called `foo`. I am not arguing that this is the best naming scheme, but from the top of my head I also see no reason to outright forbid it. The constructor would be `foo::foo::foo()` then.

Having a rule that would disallow such naming would lead to lots of frustration to anybody that wants to use such (possibly suboptimal, but thats just opinions) naming scheme while having absolutely zero gain for someone that does not want to use such naming. In total there would be no benefit.

Comment: *the fully qualified name of a constructor of class foo is foo::foo()* -  **15.1 Constructors [class.ctor] 1 Constructors do not have names.**

Comment: @VTT thanks for pointing it out, I knew there was something not right, what is it then if constructors dont have a name?

Comment: I'd say that the problem with `x::y::x` is that introduction of `x::y::x` will cause `x::` used in `x::y::` scope to silently change meaning. I think there is a special term for this (at least in context of Ada language), but I just can't recall it.

Comment: @VTT I think there are cases where you write code inside a namespace but have no control what namespace is on top and/or beneath you, I just didnt manage to come up with a meaningful example

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to variables having the same name in different scopes. Technically valid. After all, at the assembly level there are no names, just pointers and sizes.

```
void foo()
{
 int x = 1;
 if (true)
  {
   int x = 2;
   x = 3; // Whops
  }
}
```

C++ is not a forgiving language, if you mess up with anything, including variables naming, you are on your own. If you want the language to save you, there are (plenty of) other languages to pick.

That said, MSVC (and probably other compilers) issues a warning when a declared variable hides another variable in an outer scope, so by reading compiler warnings you can be helped.

Comment: The funny things start to happen when there was a code in inner scope referring to the `x` from outer scope...